# What's the geographic distribution of the father/bra split in American English?

Tags: english, phonology, vowels, american-english

In most American English dialects with the *father*/*bother* merger, the *bother* vowel (originally /ɔ/) unrounds, lowers, and merges into the *father* vowel (originally /ɑ/), with the end result being /ɑ/, the same as the original *father* vowel.

However, in the particular Central Massachusetts dialect that I grew up speaking, while the *father*/*bother* merger still takes place, it doesn't do so in the usual manner.  Instead of both vowels merging to /ɑ/, the *father* vowel undergoes what I'm going to term (for lack of having found a preexisting term in the literature) a *father*/*bra* split, with words in the *bra* group retaining /ɑ/, and the vowel in the remaining *father* group rounding and merging to /ɔ/, the same as the original *bother* vowel.<sup>1</sup>

The words in the ''bra'' group consist entirely or almost entirely of a combination of

- [At-least-relatively-]Recent loans, like *bra*, *mach*, *Nazi*, and *spa*.
- Words where the vowel in question is immediately followed by /ɹ/ without an intervening syllable break, like *star*.<sup>2</sup>

I haven't had any luck in trying to find out how wide of an area exhibits the *father*/*bra* split; does anyone here have information handy on the geographic distribution of this feature in AmE?

---

<sup>1</sup>: In the specific dialect that I picked up, this rounded *father*/*bother* vowel *also* merges with the *caught* vowel, resulting in a three-way back-vowel merger with /ɔ/ as its endpoint, but that's a tangentially-separate issue.

<sup>2</sup>: This second subset of the *bra* group escapes the merger because almost all AmE dialects, including the one I grew up with, are allergic to /ɔɹ/ occurring in a closed syllable.

Comment: What are examples of the second subset?

Comment: *baer, bore*, *born* or *borne*? I'm not sure I understand the discussion ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Etymology_scriptorium#born_vs_borne_\(vowel\))) because it says nothing of the change from past tense OE *bær*, ME *bar, ber*, ModE *bore* or (archaic) *bare*, non-standard pret. and pp. *baered*.

Comment: Anyway, this seems like on-topic for the English stack.